# Convert html to word

Tags: c#, asp.net, docx

I use docx.dll to convert html to word. But can't convert html tag. For example : html is a `p` with

`<p><em><strong>adfa à asdf asdf</strong></em></p>`

So when convert finished, the content of word file is the same

`<p><em><strong>adfa à asdf asdf</strong></em></p>` .

My code below

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void eprt_tml(int ptcn_id)
    {
        DataTable tml_tbl = DBclass.TruyVanTraVeTable1("select course_id, vname, vcontent from testimonial where contact_id='" + ptcn_id + "'");
        string course_name = DBclass.TruyVanTraVeGiaTri("select vname from course where id='"+tml_tbl.Rows[0]["course_id"]+"'");
        DataTable ptcn_tbl = DBclass.TruyVanTraVeTable1("select first_name, last_name, salutation_id, title from contact where id='"+ptcn_id+"'");
        string ptcn_name = ptcn_tbl.Rows[0]["last_name"].ToString() + " " + ptcn_tbl.Rows[0]["first_name"].ToString();
        DocX g_document;

        try
        {

            // Store a global reference to the loaded document.
            g_document = DocX.Load(@"D:\Project\CRM1\tml\tml_tpt.docx");
            /*
             * The template 'InvoiceTemplate.docx' does exist, 
             * so lets use it to create an invoice for a factitious company
             * called "The Happy Builder" and store a global reference it.
             */
            g_document = crt_from_tpl(DocX.Load(@"D:\Project\CRM1\tml\tml_tpt.docx"), course_name, tml_tbl.Rows[0]["vname"].ToString(), tml_tbl.Rows[0]["vcontent"].ToString(), ptcn_name, ptcn_tbl.Rows[0]["title"].ToString());
            // Save all changes made to this template as Invoice_The_Happy_Builder.docx (We don't want to replace InvoiceTemplate.docx).
            g_document.SaveAs(@"D:\Project\CRM1\tml\Invoice_The_Happy_Builder.docx");
        }

            // The template 'InvoiceTemplate.docx' does not exist, so create it.
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {

        }

    }

    //Create tml from template
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    private static DocX crt_from_tpl(DocX template, string course_name, string vname, string vcontent, string ptcn_name, string ptcn_title)
    {
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("static_title", "Ứng Dụng Thực Tiễn Thành Công"));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("tmlname", vname));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("tmlcontent", vcontent));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("ptcnname", ptcn_name));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("ptcntitle", ptcn_title));
        template.AddCustomProperty(new CustomProperty("coursename", course_name));
        return template;
    }
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Thank ParPar, but my code still work well, i only want to replace or remove html tag. have any tool to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines to your code just before saving the document..

```
g_document.ReplaceText(@"<p><em><strong>","");
g_document.ReplaceText(@"</strong></em></p>","");
```

Note: It will just remove the html tages, but without adding any formatting.

Comment: I think the OP wants a more generic solution than this.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I think so, but did you check Hainlp's reply in comment to ParPar Basically converting HTML to DOC itself is a bad idea, as ASP.NET will render html from its own server side tags - instead of HTML tags.

Comment: My application : user post an article in my web via CKeditor. Then user want to export this article to .docx file and use it to print. So can't use ReplaceText to replace html tag.

Comment: @Hainlp I guess there are no straight forward solutions for what you are looking for, as converting HTML to WORD will never guarantee formatting consistency. Please check http://notesforhtml2openxml.codeplex.com/ and see if its useful for you.  Regards.

Comment: @Flowerking : openxml is too limited to resolve my problem becasue the  .docx file template must have headder, foooter, background image, logo.. So i think need other tool to combine with DocX

Comment: @Hainlp OpenXML is capable of doing whatever you want to do with a word document. Please Check this E-Book - http://goo.gl/a3Nl7, also please check http://openxmldeveloper.org , The only con is it takes a bit more time to learn and understand.

Answer (score 0):

Open your HTML file with Word, click on "Save as" and choose "Word document" under "File type".

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows PC I have installed Microsoft Office 2016. You will have to add COM reference to your .NET core project at path

C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\OFFICE.DLL

You have to first save your HTML string as .HTML file and then use the below function to load that HTML file to word document and then save it as *.docx file.
You can use below C# function to convert HTML text to word doc

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using Application = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
using Document = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
using Paragraph = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph;


    public void SaveHtmlAsWordFile(string htmlFilePath)
    {
        string wordFile = htmlFilePath.Replace(".html",".docx");
        // Create an instance of the Word application
        Application wordApp = new Application();

        // Open the HTML file
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(htmlFilePath);

        // Save the document as a .docx file
        doc.SaveAs2(wordFile, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault);

        // Close the document and the Word application
        doc.Close();
        wordApp.Quit();
    }
```

[image]

[image]